# How do I pass a DataTable back to the calling method?

Tags: c#, object, datatable

I have been trying to pass a `DataTable` back to the calling method.  Here is the code that calls the `Class` to create the `DataTable`.

```
string SQL = "SELECT .....";
Tables.Create_DataTable(SQL);
```

Here is the code for the class `Tables`.

```
public static class Tables
{
    internal static object Create_DataTable(string SQL)
    {
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable("Work_Orders");

        using (DataAccessClass.sql_Connection)
        using (SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(SQL, DataAccessClass.sql_Connection))
        {
            DataAccessClass.OpenConnection();

            sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
        }

        return Work_Orders;
    }
}
```

Right after the `sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);` there is a `Work_Orders DataTable` containing the requested data.  On the return, I realize that the `DataTable` is actually an `object`.  This is where I get stuck.  How do I change the `object` to a `DataTable`? Then I will add it to the `DataSet`.

Comment: You need to change `internal static object Create_DataTable(string SQL)` to `internal static DataTable Create_DataTable(string SQL)`. Can't you do that?

Comment: @DaveHampel I would suggest going back to the section in the C# basics tutorials and focus on return type with Methods / Functions.also  you would be returning dataTable, plus changing the method signature to return a type of DataTable..

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya, Thanks very much.  That did the trick.  I did have to change the calling code to `DataTable Work_Orders = Tables.Create_Work_Orders_Table(SQL);` then I was able to add the table to my `DataSet`.

Comment: Also, I would strongly recommend removing the class level `sql_Connection` and create a local instance of `SqlConnection` inside a `using` statement instead. [See what Microsoft have to say about it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling#adding-connections)

Comment: Your function does not create a table, but returns the content of the table existing in your database. You should change the return statement to return the `dataTable` variable and if would be wise the change the signature also (should return `DataTable` instead `object` for data type consistency)

Comment: @ZoharPeled I will take a look at your suggestion.  thanks

Comment: @DaveHampel if individuals do not show effort in regards to your case, knowing how to as well as understanding the return type of what you are working with, this would constitute downvoting by others . if you know you want to return a `DataTable` then the return type should be of that type. or you should read up as well on how to Cast Objects into specific datatypes. respectfully speaking. also read up on how to access the underlying datatable if you are returning a DataSet by it's `DataSet.Tables[]` method / property too

Comment: @MethodMan I will be reading and refreshing myself on Casting Objects.

Comment: @ZoharPeled can I send you my connection class and then you can tell me what you think is wrong with it?

Comment: @DaveHampel regardless of being a comment the one that solved your problem, it could help others with your same problem having an answer marked as accepted. That way other people could notice the problem got solved.

Comment: @DaveHampel No, but you can post it on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) if you want someone to look at it. That way, you get the benefit of multiple people reviewing your code. If you do post it, you can comment with `@ZoharPeled` on it if you want me to look at it.

Answer (score 3):

You should return `dataTable` from your method, but as the basic question the signature should be :

```
attributes modifiers return-type method-name(parameters )
    {
     statements
    }
```

Take a look at [Here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_methods.htm) or [Here](http://csharp-station.com/Tutorial/CSharp/Lesson05)

But change your method like:

```
internal static DataTable Create_DataTable(string SQL)
{
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable("Work_Orders");

    using (DataAccessClass.sql_Connection)
    using (SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(SQL, DataAccessClass.sql_Connection))
    {
        DataAccessClass.OpenConnection();

        sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
    }

    return dataTable;
}
```

**EDIT:**

1- Avoid to return Object from a method

2- Avoid returning DataTable from a method also

because both of them make your code unreadable and unclean, so this is better to return an object which specified for example suppose your DataTable have some fileds about user then this better to be like:

if DataTable have one row:

```
internal static User Create_DataTable(string SQL)
{
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable("Work_Orders");

    using (DataAccessClass.sql_Connection)
    using (SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(SQL, DataAccessClass.sql_Connection))
    {
        DataAccessClass.OpenConnection();

        sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
    }
     User u = new User()
       { 
          Name = dataTable.Rows[0]("Name"),
          Family = dataTable.Rows[0]("Family"),
          UserName = dataTable.Rows[0]("UserName")
        }
    return u;
}
```

or if DataTable have infos about several users (Have some rows):

```
internal static List<User> Create_DataTable(string SQL)
{
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable("Work_Orders");

    using (DataAccessClass.sql_Connection)
    using (SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(SQL, DataAccessClass.sql_Connection))
    {
        DataAccessClass.OpenConnection();

        sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
    }
     List<User> uList = new List<User>();
     foreach (DataRow row in Datatable.Rows) 
     { 
         uList.Add(new User()
              { 
                   Name = row["Name"],
                   Family = row["Family"],
                   UserName = row["UserName"]
               });
      }
    return uList;
}
```

The above code just are samples.

Comment: this is the answer but I figured it out with the help of @ChetanRanpariya a minute or 2 before this answer was posted.  thanks anyway

Comment: @DaveHampel, Of course, everybody knows that signature should be change, but I posted the answer to help other C# newbies, anyway you can accept it or not.